# Multithreading with windows forms C#

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, winforms, visual-studio

I am trying to make a windows form appliation that displays all the Tasks that are running while they are running. I want to stop tasks individually if I want to. I have the application working as a console application but when I try to build it as a windows form application it screws up. Here is how my code works.

- Loop

  - Make a task
  - store it in a list
  - start the task=
- End Loop

I want to display this list in a listView in my form and update it every few seconds displaying the name and status of this task.Can somebody help me with that or suggest good reads to study multithreading.
Thanks.

Comment: can you provide the code?

Comment: *"when I try to build it as a windows form application it screws up"* You never told us what is actually wrong, please explain in detail what errors you are getting (if any) and what behavior you are seeing and what behavior you expect to see. Also please include any code that may be relevant to the error.

Comment: "it screws up" - surely the problem is more specific than this?  Like, maybe there is an _exception_ in there?

Comment: Just to add my two cents.
Good read is parallel programming with .net
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963549.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have the application working as a console application but when I try to build it as a windows form application it screws up.

Provided that you didn't change your logic during the port to Windows Forms, this is likely due to updating the Windows Forms controls from the background thread within your Task.

You can only use Windows Forms controls from the main (UI) thread, and not from a background thread.  If you want to perform an update to the UI, you need to use [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) or [`Control.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) to marshal the call back onto the UI thread.

Comment: I feel that it is likely that this is the problem, but I didn't want to jump to any conclusions till we got more details from the OP.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yeah - I questioned it, but given that the OP specified they had a "working version in a console app" and switched to windows forms, and it's not working, this is, by and large, the #1 issue with threading and Windows Forms, so I'd give it a very high probability of being the issue :)